# How do I convert a DateTimeOffset? to DateTime in C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, datetime

I need to convert a DateTimeOffset? to a DateTime. The value originally comes from a XAML CalendarDatePicker, but I need to change it to DateTime to store the value. I have found  [this description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546101(v=vs.110).aspx) of how to convert DateTimeOffset, but I do not think that it answers my question because they don't use a nullable type.

Comment: Why not convert it to nullable DateTime then?

Comment: Because it still does not work.

Comment: Nullable types aren't magic. Just extract the DateTimeOffset value with .... `.Value` and convert it to local or UTC time before saving. The linked article shows how to do this.

Comment: Can you be more specific - post the code you have tried and exactly which bit fails.

Comment: @S.B.Wrede *what* doesn't work? What did you try? Did you try `myValue.Value.LocalDateTime` or `myValue.Value.UtcDateTime`?

Comment: BTW you should consider storing DateTimeOffset *instead* of DateTime to avoid mixing up times. Otherwise, prepare for bugs at least twice a year when DST changes - not to mention the trouble you'll have storing times that refer to different timezones

Comment: @S.B.Wrede, could you please paste some code?

Comment: I am only interested in the month, year and date. The CalendarDatePicker actually only gives the user the option to choose month, year and date. 
It worked with myValue.Value.LocalDateTime, so thank you for that.

Answer (score 15):

[*Nullable*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx) types are useful, but can sometimes be confusing at first. The `Nullable<T>` is a struct where T is a struct as well.  This struct wraps the value for the instance variable T and exposes three primary members.

```
HasValue // Returns bool indicating whether there is a value present.

Value // Returns the value of T if one is present, or throws.

GetValueOrDefault() // Gets the value or returns default(T).
```

You can make any struct nullable by adding a '`?`' after the declaration of the variable type, or by wrapping the variable type with `Nullable<` varible type here `>`. As depicted below:

```
Nullable<DateTimeOffset> a = null;
DateTimeOffset? b = null;
```

I believe that what you would want here is to check if there is in fact a value with `.HasValue` and then take the `.Value` from the offset and perform your standard conversion.

**Example**

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
DateTimeOffset? offset = now;
DateTime dateTime = offset.HasValue ? offset.Value.DateTime : DateTime.MaxValue;
```

Or if you want a `DateTime?` do this:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
DateTimeOffset? offset = now;
DateTime? dateTime = offset.HasValue ? offset.Value.DateTime : (DateTime?)null;
```

Comment: but how  do actually I convert from DateTimeOffset? to DateTime? ?

Comment: @DmytroZhluktenko I have updated the answer to include this.

Comment: Oh, thanks!
Actually, I already solved it, please update your answer to
`DateTime? dateTime = offset.HasValue ? offset.Value.DateTime : (DateTime?) null;`
because there is no implicit conversion between DateTime and null.

Comment: Not sure why this wasn't accepted as the answer.  Worked like a charm.

Comment: Short and exact solution. Must be accepted as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since C# 6.0, we can use the Null-Conditional Operator:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
DateTimeOffset? offset = now;
DateTime? dateTime = offset?.DateTime
```